# Form validation in PHP - switch statement

Tags: php, validation

I'm working on a homework assignment that involves validating a form with PHP. The homework asks that I do this through a switch statement, but I'm running in to issues. I am not sure where I'm going wrong so I'm going to include all of PHP code:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

$firstname = $_POST["firstname"];
$lastname = $_POST["lastname"];
$street = $_POST["street"];
$city = $_POST["city"];
$state = $_POST["state"];
$zip = $_POST["zip"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$payment = $_POST["payment"];

$storeNV = array("firstname" => "", "lastname" => "", "street" => "", "city" => "", "state" => "", "zip" => "",
    "email" => "", "payment" => "");

$inputNames = array_keys($storeNV);

foreach ($inputNames as $name) {
    $storeNV[$name] = "$_POST[$name]"; 
}

foreach ($storeNV as $name => $value) {
    if (isset($value) == false OR $value == "") {
        $blankError = "Something was left blank!";
        print "<h1>$blankError</h1>";
        break; #just one error message
    }
}

switch ($name) {
    case 'firstname' :
        if (empty($storeNV[firstname)) {
            $fnameError = "Required field";
        break;
        }
    case 'lastname' :
        if (empty($storeNV[lastname])) {
            $lnameError = "Required field";
        break;
        }
     case 'street' :
        if (empty($storeNV[street])) {
            $streetError = "Required field";
        break;
     }
     case 'city' :
        if (empty($storeNV[city])) {
            $cityError = "Required field";
        break;
     }
     case 'state' :
        if (!preg_match("/^[A-ZA-Z]*$/", trim($value))) {
            $stateError = "Standard state abbrieviations only";
        break;
        }
    case 'zip' :
        if (!preg_match("/^[0-9]{5}*$/", trim($value))) {
            $zipError = "Standard 5-digit zip codes only";
        break;
        }
     case 'email' :
        if (!filter_var($storeV[email], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $emailError = "Invalid email";
        break;
        }
     case 'payment' :
        if (empty($storeNV[payment])) {
            $paymentError = "Please select one";
        break;
        }
}
?>
```

The error messages are then inserted with more PHP in the HTML like this:

```
<span class="error"><?php echo $fnameError;?></span>
```

The problem is that when I try to run the form validation, I get a bunch of these:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: fnameError
```

I think I am going wrong somewhere in the switch statement, possibly in the syntax of the cases, but I've been staring at this long enough that I don't think I can ever figure it out on my own.

Comment: well, the error you're getting tells you that you DON'T have an error in validating the firstName (because you don't set it). But what is your problem in general?

Comment: you maybe should check first if you have an error and only try to display them if you have any. I'd push them into an array `valErrors` and check for length of that array.

Comment: and why are you checking twice if the values are empty?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the variable $fnameError is undefined as stated. This can happen when fname passes validation. There are two ways around this...

Either you first declare all your error variables as such

```
$fnameError = "";
$emailError = "";
```

etc. Or check if the variable exists before echoing like

```
<span class="error"><?php if(isset($fnameError)) echo $fnameError;?></span>
```